could not create parent directories
AL COMPILAR MAVEN EN NETBEANS 19 CON JDK 21me tira este error al compilar el proyecto

llevo como 2 dias intentandolo solucionar y no encuentro solucion alguna

Hola Martin, el código y mensajes  de error como texto, sino te cerrarán la pregunta.

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.
